# Read excel folder with some containing worksheets in R

Tags: r, excel, rstudio, worksheet

I have a folder containing excel files. There are some that have worksheets and I just want to know how to use a special case (maybe a for loop) where I would identify which files need to be used to read worksheets and then select only certain tabs to join all of the excel files together at the end. In addition, these tabs would need to skip 40 lines which I assume would use skip=40. When I type the code that I have, it looks like a giant mess.

```
files <- list.files(path = "/Users/Desktop/folder2, pattern = "*.xlsx")
files_join <- lapply(files, read_excel) %>%
    bind_rows()
```

Comment: Do you know which tabs you would need?  `excel_sheets()` from the same readxl package lists the sheets in a file, and then you would need a way to know which sheets to select to pass to `read_excel()`

Comment: Yes, I have five files and two of them have worksheets, other three don't. From those two files, I need 2 worksheets from each.

Comment: Sorry I had to go in the field and I see you have no answers.  I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: No worries, I already solved my problem. Thank you!!